# displaying camera on rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, camera, camera-info, sensor

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
i'm trying to display a camera on rviz, the source is a camera on [Gazebo](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gazebo).
rviz shows me that:

> > CameraInfo                 -> No CameraInfo received on [/finger_tip_cam/camera_info].  Topic may not exist.

> > image                      -> No image received.

> > Transform [sender/=Gazebo] -> No CameraInfo received on [/finger_tip_cam/camera_info].  Topic may not exist.

What could the problem be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12310/displaying-camera-on-rviz./) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2011-12-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-12**:
Try running "rostopic list", and adding an (edited) list of the relevant topics to your question.

**Comment by [Bram van de Klundert](https://answers.ros.org/users/392/bram-van-de-klundert/) on 2011-12-11**:
are you sure data is being published on those topics? how did you add the camera in gazebo? please provide something for us to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of adding a camera in rviz, try adding an image. If the publisher of this topic only updates the image and not all the information required for a ROS camera interface, rviz can not display the image.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-11-02**:
What other information is required for a ROS camera interface?

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2016-11-02**:
the `camera_info` topic